# How can I create Android .keystore to release NativeScript Angular apk

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I just created NativeScript Angular App. In order to create apk file for release `tns build android --release` requires .keystore file.

Where do I get it and What are the steps I should follow to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the commands described in [this guide](https://nativescript.org/blog/steps-to-publish-your-nativescript-app-to-the-app-stores/).

First, we need to have a "signing key" in order to make a release build.

I like the use the keytool command described above to create the *jks* file:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-android-key.jks -keyalg RSA -alias myAlias
```

If you have properly set up the Android sdk for NativeScript developement then you should have "keytool" already in your PATH so that you can use it from anywhere.

I like to make a "keys" folder in the root of my ns project. While inside of this folder, we can run the keytool command to put it there.

The keytool command starts a little interactive prompt that asks you to two different passwords.

Then back in the project root we can run the build command with the --release flag and other key flags:

```
ns build android --release --key-store-path keys/my-app-android-key.jks --key-store-password myGoodPw1 --key-store-alias myAlias --key-store-alias-password myGoodPw2
```

You may or may not need to add the `--force` flag when you do a build...

You'll know it worked when you see the success message:

```
Project successfully built.
```

Good luck!